# Laravel - set use permissions only from one ip

Tags: laravel, permissions

i want to set permissions only from on IP, because i use this app only for API and not want others peoples have permissions for that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it , using middleware you will able to check in every request the ip requesting.

[Laravel middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: Also, as an alternative, this could be handled at the HTTP server level (which would be faster as far as performance goes). Here are examples for setting this up with [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/).